# preg_match regex match more than 4 digits

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have $input which contains:

```
<a href="http://digitalocean.com/info/hello-23-kitty-show-1-d-zay-ya-9013294119" title="Hello Kitty  (Show &amp; Zay Ya" style="font-size:medium;" target="_blank" class="highlight-item">
```

I need to preg_match only those last digits in href url (9013294119). Those digits can be longer or shorter sometimes as URL's in $input varies ( but its always minimum 4 characters length).

I tried following regex expression but no luck as my regex experience is very limited:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9+]$/', $input, $output);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `^` (starts with) and `$` (ends with) anchors and use quantifiers and some lookaheads and behinds.

```
/(?<=-)[0-9]{4,}(?=")/
```

`{4,}` means match the previous token, in this case `[0-9]`, 4 or more times.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/fF1iM2/1)

If the pattern of your string isn't the same, you can use `href="[^"]+?([0-9]{4,})"` and Group 1 will contain what you want.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yup, OP hasn't given more info

Comment: Thanks, works like charm, I was getting Unknown modifier '[' error, but I've added / at start and the end adn it worked.

Comment: @DadaB if this an exact input you're trying to parse then this `[0-9]{4,}` would be enough..